# How to submit form without moving to next page in PHP

Tags: php

### The Problem

I am trying to submit a form in php but due to the nature of what i want i need the page to not go onto the next one i just want it to submit the data and refresh the current page or whatever, at current it submits the data and goes onto page 2 which i dont want i just need it to submit the data and stay on the current page, if thats possible!

### The Code

//page 1 code

```
<center>
<h1>What Is Jacob Dailey Doing?</h1>


<form method="post" action="jacob_dailey.php">

    <select name="baby_status">
        <option value="playing">Playing</option>
        <option value="awake">Awake</option>
        <option value="sleeping">Sleeping</option>
    </select>


<br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>

</center>
```

//page 2 code

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['baby_status'])) {
    $baby = $_POST['baby_status'];
    setcookie("baby_status", $baby, time() + 31556926, '/'); //  Data will Store For 1 Year
    header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
}
$status = $_COOKIE['baby_status'];
echo '<center> <h1>Baby Jacob Dailey Is Currently ' . ucwords($status) . '</h1>';
if ($status == "playing") {
    echo '<img src="http://cdn.sheknows.com/articles/2013/02/baby-playing-with-blocks.jpg"/>';
}
elseif ($status == "awake") {
    echo '<img src="http://www.westheimphoto.com/lightbox/gallery/TaiwanStockPhotos/TWNhw1221.jpg"/>';
}
elseif ($status == "sleeping") {
    echo '<img src="http://www.babycare.onlymyhealth.com/imported/images/neonatal/2012/July/19_Jul_2012/6-Months-Old-ssl.jpg"/>';
}
echo '</center>';
?>
```

Page 2 code shouldnt be as important but i just need it so when i click submit on page 1 it updates the information on page 2 but doesnt take me to page 2.

Cheers!

Comment: change action to current page

Comment: Are you only using PHP to set the cookie? Or do you expect to eventually put information in a database?

Comment: i dont want to put it in a database if i dont NEED to i just want 1 person on 1 computer to cahnge a page and someone else on another computer be able to view the page/ changes

Comment: If you want someone on another computer to view the baby status then you need to store that information on the server, either database or filesystem. The person on the other computer won't get the first person's cookie.

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles how would i go about doing this ive been told this but.. meh its hard for me lol.. reading and being shown are two different things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form can submit onto itself. Just in the `action="xyz"` either leave it (the whole `action=...` attribute) out entirely or else name the page that also contains the form there between quotes.

Then when you load the page you check the $_POST or $_GET array (depending on the method) to see if the submit button was pushed or if someone just navigated to the page.  (You'll want to give you submit button a `name="foo"`.)

Comment: When i leave it blank or change it to the same page it doesnt update the content on page 2, it stays the same.

Comment: Just do all the stuff that you are doing in page 2 - do it in the main page. Is there some reason why it has to be set over on page 2?

Comment: Yes 1 page is only to be viewed by an admin and the other by normal users so i basically need the admin to cahnge something that the user can see without the user seeing all the options the admin page controls many pages but all the pages only have 1 admin page if you get what im saying

Comment: Erm... You're not setting anything for anybody else over on page 2. Cookies are saved *locally* and so only the person who submitted would have anything changed over on page2. If someone else accessed page2 they would *not* see anything changed there. Thus the admin may be saving it, but nobody else is seeing it. If you want to save something for others you've got to do something like save it in a database or in a textfile or something like that...

Comment: Try accessing page2 using a different browser (if you usually use chrome then try with firefox or internet explorer - just a different browser.) I think you'll find that what you thought was being saved for page 2 isn't really being saved.

Comment: aah yes youre right never though of trying that this just bring me back to my whole main problem again AAARGHH its so stressful lol

Comment: Well, hopefully although the question wasn't the one you apparently should have been asking (LOL) hopefully this answer did answer that question...

Comment: You could get the current site with this function: `htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);`

Answer (score 0):

action="jacob_dailey.php" in your form takes you to that page, you either paste your php code to main page and replace action with just "" or you will search AJAX and learn how to it with that

Comment: When i leave it blank or change it to the same page it doesnt update the content on page 2, it stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery.ajax(). Example here:
http://www.formget.com/form-submission-using-ajax-php-and-javascript/

This example uses a database, but you can use a php file to return values and read them from the response in javascript. Do not put any action to the form but enable a click event handler on the submit button to enable the function.

Also my example here: http://dev.ossipesonen.fi/alkoholilaskuri/
A very simple form where you insert values, pass them onto PHP with $_POST and then calculates the right amounts and sums, and you print them in the response.

Comment: problem is i dont use jquery or ajax but thanks your answer makes sense!

Comment: You can create the form itself in the PHP by adding an if, else clause.<?php if(isset($_POST)): ?> Execute the form and print out success message <?php else: ?>  Print out form as the execution ahs not happened. Take out the action attribute from form element or put it the same as the PHP file.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:** Update Status Without Page Reload Using XHR and Filesystem Storage

If you want someone on another computer to see the update, then you'll need to store that information on the server. You could store the information in a database, but for this small bit of information I'm using the filesystem.

*page1.php*

```
<?php

// get baby status if available
if ( is_readable('baby_status.php') ) {
  include 'baby_status.php';
}
$status =  ( $status )? $status: '??';

// prepare to update select list
list($pl_check, $pl_check, $pl_check) = array('', '', '');
switch ( $status ) {
  case 'playing':  $pl_check = ' selected '; break;
  case 'awake':    $aw_check = ' selected '; break;
  case 'sleeping': $sl_check = ' selected '; break;
}

?>

<center>
<h1>What Is Jacob Dailey Doing?</h1>
<form id="baby_form" method="post" action="update_baby.php">
    <select id="baby_status" name="baby_status">
        <option value="playing" <?php echo $pl_check ?>>Playing</option>
        <option value="awake"   <?php echo $aw_check ?>>Awake</option>
        <option value="sleeping"<?php echo $sl_check ?>>Sleeping</option>
    </select><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>

<a href="page2.php">See Baby Status</a>
</center>

<script>

// XHR/PHP/Filesystem method
function update_baby () {
  var baby_status = document.getElementById('baby_status');
  var status=encodeURIComponent(baby_status.options[baby_status.selectedIndex].value)
  var parameters = 'baby_status=' + status

  // set up XHR object
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
  xhr.open('POST', 'update_baby.php', true)
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
  // handle response
  xhr.onload = function () {
    console.log(this.responseText)
    alert(this.responseText)
  }
  xhr.send(parameters) 
}

// hook up baby status function to form submit
document.getElementById('baby_form').addEventListener('submit', function(evt){
  evt.preventDefault()
  update_baby()
})

</script>
```

*page2.php*

```
<?php

// execute baby update code and get current status
include 'update_baby.php';

echo '<center> <h1>Baby Jacob Dailey Is Currently ' . ucwords($status) . '</h1>';
if ($status == "playing") {
    echo '<img src="http://cdn.sheknows.com/articles/2013/02/baby-playing-with-blocks.jpg"/>';
}
elseif ($status == "awake") {
    echo '<img src="http://www.westheimphoto.com/lightbox/gallery/TaiwanStockPhotos/TWNhw1221.jpg"/>';
}
elseif ($status == "sleeping") {
    echo '<img src="http://www.babycare.onlymyhealth.com/imported/images/neonatal/2012/July/19_Jul_2012/6-Months-Old-ssl.jpg"/>';
}

?>

<br>
<a href="page1.php">Update Baby Status</a>
</center>
```

*update_baby.php*

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['baby_status'])) {
    $status = $_POST['baby_status'];

    // prepare php script text for baby status file
    $status_write = <<<EOT
<?php

\$status = '$status';

?>
EOT;

    // write status to baby_status.php
    if ( $baby_status_file = fopen('baby_status.php', 'w') ) {
        fwrite($baby_status_file, $status_write);
        fclose($baby_status_file);
    }

    echo 'Baby status updated.';
}
else {
    if ( is_readable('baby_status.php') ) {
        include 'baby_status.php';
    }
    $status = ( $status )? $status: '??';
}

?>
```

**Note:** To use this option the directory these files are in must be writeable by the web server.